# Java Newb: Return parameter not reassigned after recursive loop

Tags: java, return

```
    static String ask(String question) {

        String Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        Answer = Answer.toUpperCase();

        System.out.println("User, " + counter +"," + Answer); // for debugging purposes
        counter += 1; // for debugging purposes

        switch (Answer){

        case "A":
            return(Answer);
        case "B":
            return(Answer);
        case "C":
            return(Answer);
        case "D":
            return(Answer);
        case "E":
            return(Answer);
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Answer.  Please Enter A,B,C,D,or E:");
            ask(question);
            // when invalid option entered, we loop back to beginning of method - Answer not being reassigned

        }
        return(Answer);  // I don't need this, Java won't let me run without it
```

after entering a few invalid entries, the parameter returned isn't reassigned with the valid entry.  example of output:

```
User, 1,U
User, 2,I
User, 3,O
User, 4,P
User, 5,M
User, 6,A
User Answer:U
CorrectAnser:A
false
```

As you can see, "U" was the first entry, and the last - "A" is the entry that escaped the loop.  Though "U" is what's returned and not "A."  Can't figure out why?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value that is returned in your recursive call. `return ask(question)`.

Comment: If you don't need to return answer, then your method return type to void.

Comment: Your style of code threw me off at first. Please take a look at standard Java coding style recommendations: https://petroware.no/javastyle.html  - Variable names should start with lower case letters (answer - not Answer) and you don't need to surround the return with parentheses: return answer; - just a comment to help.

Comment: The last return is required because you declared your method to return a String. It's possible that you would enter the Default in the switch statement and you don't return anything there and also the Java compiler will require you to have a return statement outside of the swtich block anyway.

Comment: the last return shouldn't ever be reached, each case has a return statement, and the default is to recurse.  The ```return ask(question)``` is sending question back into the method to get new valid input... I may have syntax it incorrectly though, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: The problem is that U is being returned and not A.... I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivar said in the comments, you're not returning the answer in the `default` part of your switch statement. You need to say `return ask(question` instead of just calling `ask(question)`. Then, the `return answer` part at the bottom will be unnecessary. See the code below (I've also modified it a bit to look more aesthetically pleasing).

You should realize that when you call the method again, the return statement only returns from that last method call. Therefore, in your original method call, the result of `ask(question)` is ignored (it's practically like calling a void method). Return statements don't return to the first method in the stack. That's why you need a return in your default.

```
static String ask(String question) {

        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question).toUpperCase();

        System.out.println("User, " + counter +"," + answer); // for debugging purposes
        counter += 1; // for debugging purposes

        switch (answer) {
        case "A":
        case "B":
        case "C":
        case "D":
        case "E":
            return answer;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Answer.  Please Enter A,B,C,D,or E:");
            return ask(question);
            // when invalid option entered, call method again (btw, you're not looping back, it's just recursion)
        }
}
```

Turned into a loop, this would be:

```
static String ask(String question) {
  String result = question;
  do {
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question).toUpperCase();
    switch (answer) {
        case "A":
        case "B":
        case "C":
        case "D":
        case "E":
            result = answer;
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Answer.  Please Enter A,B,C,D,or E:");
        }
  } while (result == question); //I know, I know, I'm using "==". But it should be fine because question is assigned to it at the start
  return result;
```

Imagine you have a function that takes 2 strings, hashes them both, and then returns true if the hash code of the first is greater than that of the second.

```
public boolean compareHashCodes(String s1, String s2) {
  int hash1 = hash(s1), hash2 = hash(s2);
  hash(s1);
  return hash1 > hash2;
}

public int hash(String s) {
  return s.hashCode(); //or something else
}
```

As you can see, when you call the `hash` method the first time and return an `int`, that does not mean that `compareHashCodes` also immediately returns an int. It merely stores that int into the variable `hash1`. The same happens the second time, when you put a hashCode into `hash2`. The third time, the value of `hash(s1)` is ignored, not returned, because returning ints from a method that isi supposed to return booleans would not make sense. It is only when the final statement `return hash1 > hash2` is reached that the method `compareHashCodes` actually returns.

Comment: ok, I think I'm starting to understand... I was with the understanding that a recursive function call works like a loop and would start the entire function again, but what I'm missing is that it gets called from default and stays in default waiting for further instructions, thus needing a return out.